# How to write to UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, quartz-2d

This code is not working and i do not understand the mistake.
Please help.

```
   -(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1
    {    
        int w = img.size.width;
        int h = img.size.height; 
        //lon = h - lon;
        char* text  = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        /*UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 50, 100, text, strlen(text));
        UIImage *viewImage =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSLog(@"View Image : %@",viewImage);*/

        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

        //char* text    = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];// "05/05/09";
        CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);

        //rotate text
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0, 50, text, strlen(text));
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -M_PI/4 ));
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 50, 100, text, strlen(text));
        //UIImage *compositeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
        CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
        CGContextRelease(context);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        NSLog(@"Image : %@",[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked]);

        return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];   
        //return viewImage;
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest better formatting, simplification and better explanation of what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I think the code is self explanatory of what it is suppose to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have a reason to avoid NSString UIKit additions, this will suffice:

```
+(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text 
             inImage:(UIImage*)  image 
             atPoint:(CGPoint)   point
                font:(UIFont*)   font
               color:(UIColor*)  color
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, FALSE, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [color set];
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font]; 
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work.

Make sure the string you are passing into it is not empty.

Comment: Yah string is not empty for sure.

Comment: Maybe the image you are passing in is too small for you to be able to see the results. Your code does work.